# View the ‍`yum‍` output after closing the terminal

Tags: linux, yum

I connected to `centos 7` with `SSH` and `Putty`.

I ran this command:

```
yum update
```

And closed the terminal.

Now that I'm back in the new terminal, I can see it running with this command:

```
# ps auxf | grep yum
root      5455 10.3  1.3 646196 222248 pts/1   S+   04:16   1:50      \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/yum update
```

But the question is, how can I see the instant output of the command like the first time I ran it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't. You may be able to get some idea of what's going on by following `/var/log/yum.log`.

If you had started `yum update` under the control of a screen multiplexing tool like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), you could detach and re-attach to the running process.

There are some things you can do with [gdb](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/), but they're all a bit hacky. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin) for a discussion of the topic.

Comment: @StephenKitt Would you believe...that I already don't tell people they can't do something unless I'm absolutely sure? I might be wrong, and thanks for the pointer (a link would have been nice), but no thanks for the attitude.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to offend (and I can see why my comment can cause offense, sorry again). The link is in the linked Q&A above, but I should have included it directly: [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) can re-attach processes to the current terminal.

Comment: @StephenKitt the "reptyr" was great.